# Use chromium without any flash plugin

Tags: flash, chromium

Some websites already support the html5 video format. But some do not.
Chromium tells me [here](https://watch.nba.com/video/2016/12/09/0021600341-hou-okc-recap) that

```
this video cannot be played on this devise
```

I read that there are lightspark (latest release 2013-03-16) and gnash  as alternative standalone players.

Is it not possible to get a browser plug as flash alternative to play videos?

I also am not able to play this video with firefox (all plugins disabled)

Stack:

- Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
- firefox 50.0.2
- chromium 53.0.2785.143

Answer (score 0):

Installing `adobe-flashplugin` from [Canonical Partner](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner) should give you Flash plugins for both Firefox and Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have alterntives you have to force chrome to use them.[Example](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-flash-html5/omimccinlhlkpjaeaocglgmkbelejlhj)

or you can try this : [html5ify](https://github.com/leonardehrenfried/html5ify)